# Manually escaping commas on SQL statements

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping

I have a **yuzeyKo** (varchar) table which containing some coordinates like this : **23,45** (longitude,latitude)

For example i will execute an SQL like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE yuzeyKo = 29,59;
```

But (ofcourse) this isn't working. There is a syntax error because i have to escape comma on `WHERE yuzeyKo = 29,59;`

But there isn't any special escape character for commas. What should i do?

I'm using MySQL .

Comment: I vote for using an ORM layer that will handle this kind of thing automatically for you.

Comment: What is the datatype of the yuzeyKo field?

Comment: Why would you ever use a `varchar` type for a field which clearly denotes a decimal?

Comment: I'm really wondering why they're voting -1 . Can't we ask any question ? I'm not SQL guru ;) Also, i researched it **before asking** . But i research **using comma on sql statement** , **SQL escaping characters** and **escape character for comma on SQL** . I didn't noticed, i have to use *29,59* as string and i have to use quotes (`yuzeyKo = '29,59';`)

Comment: If the comma is supposed to be a decimal separator in a numeric literal, then you should be using a period instead. Numeric literals must use a period as a decimal separator, as specified in the SQL standard. If the comma is supposed to separate a pair of numbers, then you should instead be using two separate columns. Columns in the relational model are supposed to be simple, not compound.

Comment: @BalusC, because it's containing a comma . What type should i use? (I'm a SQL student ;) i will be glad i you suggest something.

Comment: @outis, i think you misunderstood. It's not a decimal seperator. That's longitudes and latitudes. It's format is : **longitude(comma)latitude** .

Comment: @Eray: hence the conditional "if". Note I also mention what you should do if the comma separates a pair of numbers. If this is to be part of a GIS, you could also use a [Point](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gis-class-point.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is yuseyKo column a VARCAHR column? if so should your SQL query be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE yuzeyKo = '29,59';
```

Comment: It's a varchar and it will work if we use `29,59` as string, as you said . Thank you @Cubicle Jockey

Answer (score 1):

you probably need something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE yuzeyKo = '29,59';
```

this is assuming your `yuzeyKo` field is some kind of character type.

Comment: It's a varchar and it will work if we use `29,59` as string, as you said . Thank you @Dmitry